# Specifying full library name in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

In a `CMakeLists.txt` file I have the following line:

```
add_library(foo MODULE foo.cpp)
```

which generates the file `libfoo.so`

I would like to specify the full file name for output (e.g. `foo.mytest`) in the CMakeLists file without manually changing the file name through external commands, is this possible with a standard cmake macro or function?

Comment: ...can't you just do `add_library(test.mytest MODULE test.cpp)`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few [properties](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) you can set on the target itself. `PREFIX` and `SUFFIX` are the ones you need:

```
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES PREFIX "" SUFFIX ".mytest")
```

You can also mess with the base name using the property `OUTPUT_NAME`, and should you ever find yourself on Windows and needing import libraries, the matching properties `IMPORT_PREFIX` and `IMPORT_SUFFIX`.